# Please make [sql-ce-4] a synonym of [sql-server-ce-4]

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms

I would suggest to "map" the [sql-ce-4](/questions/tagged/sql-ce-4) tag to be a synonym of [sql-server-ce-4](/questions/tagged/sql-server-ce-4) to be in line with other synonyms in the SQL Server area.

Can't create a suggestion for that myself, since I'm not a moderator (version specific synonyms are for mods only) ....

Comment: "Version specific synonyms are for mods only" I had no idea. Is that documented somewhere? Or do you just get an error when you try to propose them?

Comment: @Cody Gray: got an error trying to propose....

Comment: @Cody: It's probably just the standard "you need 5 score in this tag to propose a synonym." It's certainly not an issue with rep. ;)